# Toss two fair coins $N$ times, what is the probability that you see in a head in the first coin before the second coin?

Tags: probability

Say I have two fair coins $a$ and $b$, and I toss them both $N$ times independently, so for $N = 1$, my event space is $\left\{ \left(H,H\right),\left(H,T\right),\left(T,H\right),\left(T,T\right)\right\} $.
So for $N$ tosses I have two events $A$ and $B$, they are:

$$A="x_{1}\dots x_{N}:\ x_{i}\in\left\{ H,T\right\}" $$

$$B="y_{1},\dots,y_{N}:\ y_{i}\in\left\{ H,T\right\} "$$

What is the probability that I see a head in $a$ *before* I see a head in $b$? I would like to say $\frac{1}{2}$ but it's clearly not that even for $N = 1$. For $N = 1$ it's $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: It is 1/2(1-P(they both first have heads on same toss)-P(neither has heads after N tosses)).

Answer (score 1):

One way to work this out is to "list" all the ways coin $A$ might come
up heads before coin $B$ does. They are:
\begin{align}
&(T,H)\\
&(T,T), (T,H) \\
&(T,T), (T,T),  (T,H) \\
&(T,T), (T,T), (T,T),  (T,H) \\
&\qquad \vdots \\
&(T,T), (T,T),  \ldots, (T,T),  (T,H) \\
\end{align}

where the last line is a sequence of $N$ pairs.
These are disjoint events, so one need merely take the sum of their
probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

For $N=1$
P(Head in A in First Throw and Tail in B in First Throw)
$=\dfrac{1}{2^2}$

For $N=2$
P[(Head in A in First Throw and Tail in B in First Throw) OR
 (Tail in A in First Throw and Head in A in Second Throw and Tail in A in First Throw and Tail in B in second row)
$\left[\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\dfrac{1}{2^4}\right]$

Similarly For $N=3$
$\left[\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\dfrac{1}{2^4}+\dfrac{1}{2^6}\right]$

So, in general, $\sum_{p=1}^{N}\dfrac{1}{2^{2p}}$